# AngularJS: What is this directive doing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a some experience with AngularJS and have come across this directive on the web, but it is not like anything I have seen before and I am unable to comprehend what it is doing? Can anyone help?

Specific questions: With the little understanding, the signature of the directive must be doing dependency injection. But what I am struggling with is: if $injector is passed in the array, why is it also sent as a parameter in function i.e. function($injector); in other words why are there two $injectors? What will not work if I dont send the $injector in the array?

Also how is it that this directive has got controller embedded? When do you define such controllers?

Also I normally see scope with a $ prefix in the the code below how is it working without a $?

Any links to read more or explaining it here will be useful.

```
.directive('mycomp', [
    '$injector', function($injector) {
      var $builder, $compile, $drag;
      $builder = $injector.get('$builder');
      $drag = $injector.get('$drag');
      $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          component: '=mycomp'
        },
        controller: 'mycompController',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          scope.copyObjectToScope(scope.component);
          $drag.draggable($(element), {
            mode: 'mirror',
            defer: false,
            object: {
              componentName: scope.component.name
            }
          });
          return scope.$watch('component.template', function(template) {
            var view;
            if (!template) {
              return;
            }
            view = $compile(template)(scope);
            return $(element).html(view);
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is it also sent as a parameter in function i.e. function($injector); in other words why are there two $injectors?

When doing array-type injection it really doesn't matter how parameter in function is called, it will map to array items. For example, if we have

```
['$injector', function(a) {..}]
```

Parameter `a` will map to `$injector` instance, and if we have

```
['$injector', '$scope', function(a, b) {..}]
```

`a` will map to `$injector` instance and `b` will map to `$scope` instance. The order here is what matters. More here: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 in A **Note on Minification** section.

> What will not work if I dont send the $injector in the array?

If you don't, $injector will be undefined, some of that explained above.

> Also how is it that this directive has got controller embedded? When do you define such controllers?

Some directives can have controllers if needed, they should hold some heavier logic, $scope binding and so on. *link* function actually should hold only interactions with $element. 
More here: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

> Also I normally see scope with a $ prefix in the the code below how is it working without a $?

In this case `scope` is used in link function and it is NOT an injectible. In this case it is a simple variable `scope` which refers to controllers scope. You can call it `superBigVariableName` and it would still refer to scope and would still work.
So keep in mind, that link function is actually a simple function where first attribute is scope, second is element, third is attributes, you can't inject services into your link function (do that logic in controller)

Comment: a very good explanation thanks, can you suggest a good link for the more complex stuff on embedding controllers in directives (to support your explanation from your last paragraph, not that it doesn't answer but for expanding my knowledge on these)?

Comment: Maybe here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2446-using-controllers-in-directives-in-angularjs.htm it's not very common and well documented thing :[